# Why we can't create aux.js file in hoc folder in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating one project in reactjs when i create a folder hoc and in that folder we create aux.js file then it is giving error so please suggest me how to create aux.js file in hoc folder.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What error do you have ? What is a "aux.js" file ? What is your "hoc" folder ? How do you create this file ?

Comment: please add more description about your problem and error message

Answer (score 0):

aux is a reserved filename on Windows.You can try with different filename like for example reactAux.

Answer (score 0):

Aux.js or aux.js is **reserved filename** in windows. So you cant create a name with that filename.

instead you can name the hoc as follows,

**Auxilary.js 

ReactAux.js**

BUt you can name Hoc filename as Aux.js in **Mac**.